# Trying to make a math game, but the math isn't working

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a simple multiplication game. I had the code like this at first

```
m = 1
total = 3
print "Which Multiplication tables do you want to practice?"
toPractice = raw_input()

while m <= total: 
    print "What is %s times %s" % (toPractice, m)
    answer = raw_input('Your Answer: ')
    print answer

    if answer == toPractice * m:
        print "Correct!"
        m = m + 1

    else: 
        print "Answer %s is incorrect." % (answer)
        print 'Correct Answer: ', toPractice * m # For testing
        m = m + 1 # For testing
```

But doing this just made the multiplication table you were doing (12, for example) show as 1212 on 12 * 2, 121212 on 12 * 3, etc. So I converted it to an integer.

```
toPractice = raw_input()
toPractice = int(toPractice)
```

But when I do this it will say that the answer to 12 * 2 is 24 but it says the answer is incorrect. I've asked friends and tried searching around and can't figure out why it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget: `raw_input` always returns a `str`. Multiplying a string just repeats it, e.g. `"12" * 3 = "121212"`. You'll need to convert the input to an integer using the `int` function:

```
answer = raw_input('Your Answer: ')
answer = int(answer)
```

Or the shorter way:

```
answer = int(raw_input('Your Answer: '))
```

You'll need to do this for each input in your program which expects a number.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an integer of their answer, too!

```
if int(answer) == toPractice * m:
```

Comment: I believe that Python doesn't actually cast things. `int` is a function that takes some object and constructs a new integer out of it, whereas casting is more like taking what the data itself is and interpreting it differently. (So casting isn't the right word here, methinks.)

Comment: Fair point, I suppose it's really creating a new object, as the string object is immutable.